# Mysql Memory Storage Engine biggest text size possible

Tags: mysql, memory

i have a chat system using Storage Engine [Memory] but varchar 255 is way too short, what field type should i use? I dont plan on indexing this field.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't use blob or text in a memory table, but you may be able to use a longer varchar depending on your version of MySQL:

> Values in VARCHAR columns are
>   variable-length strings. The length
>   can be specified as a value from 0 to
>   255 before MySQL 5.0.3, and 0 to
>   65,535 in 5.0.3 and later versions.
>   The effective maximum length of a
>   VARCHAR in MySQL 5.0.3 and later is
>   subject to the maximum row size
>   (65,535 bytes, which is shared among
>   all columns) and the character set
>   used.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/char.html

Answer (score 0):

The Memory engine does not support BLOB/TEXT, so char/varchar is all you've got available. Details [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/memory-storage-engine.html) (search for 'blob')